# Body Onload() with submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onload

I'm using body `onload()` event to call service but issue is, the thing is not working my `webCenter` site as soon as body `onload()` works site gets loaded again it makes call to body `onload()` again ??

Comment: <body onload='init()'>?

Comment: not working !! like content on my site is loading dynamically...like some products...so i have used autosubmit after service call....but each time autosubmit occurs on onload..so again again page gets submitted..without autosubmit i cant get data !!

Comment: It sounds to me, without looking at your code, you have created a onload/submit loop.  I do not understand why you are doing any kind of submit on your load.

Comment: i want to use data which is retrieved from my service call and pass on that data to my other elements which will use it as identification to load other elements...have to use submit!

Comment: load brings me the data and submit lets me to put data in other elements!

Comment: You should be using ajax to get the data without a submit and query and javascript to populate your elements.

Comment: I'm using onload() on that ajax call to service....after success on ajax im autosubmitting the form pass that data from my hidden element to other element to load other contains dynamically !!

Comment: can you put up some of your code?

Comment: As @Bindrid said you created a load/submit loop. Submit will always reload the page. If you don't want so use ajax to transmit your data to the server and get the data to populate your elements. Submitting the form should only be used to transmit accurate data to the server.